# Add pagination to load () or any solution Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8, laravel-controller

Please how i can add paginate to my show method ? I have connect models and i need to have select by region and pagination.

```
    public function show(Tournament $tournament) {
    
     $tournament->load('region');

     return view('tournaments.show', compact('tournament')); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth. like this:

```php
public function show(Tournament $tournament) {
    
    $tournament->load('region');

    return view('tournaments.show', [
        'tournament' => $tournament->paginate();
    ]);
}
```

Here you [lazy eagerly loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) `region` and then apply the pagination to your `$tournament` object.